# How can I get a change to a .desktop file get recognized by Unity/Gnome?

Tags: .desktop

Unity/Gnome does not appear to pickup changes to .desktop files automatically (in particular the "Name" and "Icon" fields).

I have found `update-desktop-database`, but that seems to update the MIME database only (and does not look into ~/.local/share/applications (according to strace)).

After logging out and in again, the changes get recognized, but I would like to use a more convenient method of course.

Comment: Hey did you ever find a solution for this? :)

Comment: @Noitidart no, not as far as I remember.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refresh launcher icon application menu in ubuntu 12.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/500544/how-to-refresh-launcher-icon-application-menu-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Assuming you are referring to the (Unity) launcher, the link above "restarts" the icon in the Launcher and updates all properties / changes you mad in the `.desktop` file. Let me know if anything is unclear.